# Is it possible to put an <if> Condition in a select Query

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from categories ;
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------------
| category_id | T1                 | T2              | T3
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------------
|           2 | Popcorn            | Bucket          | NULL
|           3 | Popcorn            | Jumbo           | NULL
|           3 | Popcorn            | Jumbo           | NULL
            6 | Popcorn            | Combo Relish    | NULL                |
            7 | Soft Drinks        | Fountain        | Apple               |
            7 | Soft Drinks        | Fountain        | Apple               |
            8 | Soft Drinks        | Fountain        | Orange              |
            8 | Soft Drinks        | Bottled         | Orange              |
```

I have a table called **categories** as shown above .

**For Some T2 Values the T3 can be Null or can have Value .**

I have got  a query as shown below

```
select t1, t2, 
    group_concat(concat(t3,'(',category_id,')')) consildated_Data 
from categories
group by 1,2;
```

With this the results looks like this

```
Popcorn            | Bucket          | NULL
Popcorn            | Combo Relish    | NULL
Popcorn            | Jumbo           | NULL
Soft Drinks        | Fountain        | Apple(7),Apple(7),Orange(8)
Soft Drinks        | Bottled         | Orange(8)
```

My question is that if T3 is `null` , can i have the value printed as empty with corresponding `category_id` number ??

so that it looke like this for Bucket

```
Popcorn            | Bucket          | empty(2)
Popcorn            | Jumbo           | empty(3),empty(3)
```

Is it possible to put a if condition under the above query ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing, you can use an [IF statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) like this:

```
SELECT
    t1,
    t2,
    IF(
        t3 IS NULL,                                  -- condition
        CONCAT('empty(', category_id, ')'),          -- true reaction
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t3,'(',category_id,')')) -- false reaction
    ) AS consildated_Data
FROM categories
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: why field `t3` is not grouped by but can use outside a grouping functions?

Comment: @fish_ball MySQL will allow "broken" use of non grouped fields, but this query won't give the correct result if one of the `popcorn | jumbo | null` rows is changed to `popcorn | jumbo | orange`.

Answer (score 2):

use `ifnull(x, [defalt_value])` in mysql

```
select t1, t2, 
    group_concat(concat(ifnull(t3, ''),'(',category_id,')')) consildated_Data 
from categories
group by 1,2;
```

or you can also use `CASE statment`, but an uglier approach:

```
select t1, t2, 
    group_concat(concat(case t3 when null then '' else t3 end)),'(',category_id,')')) consildated_Data 
from categories
group by 1,2;
```

Comment: @VigneshKumar you'd be wrong: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: @fish_ball Should those empty quotes have "empty" inside them?

Comment: @scrowler which do you mean **those empty quotes**?

Comment: `ifnull(t3, '')` -> `ifnull(t3, 'empty')`: to fulfill the OP's requirement of having `empty(n)` in place of `Apple(n)` for example

Comment: @scrowler you can put any statement which evaluates to a valid value there.